# Open Source New Relic alternative

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, newrelic

I'm searching for a open source alternative for New Relic. Something that I can install on my own for my rails development and production app, to analyse my queries, render times... There are a lot of services out there, most of them with a free plan. But I want to host that thing on my own, install it for development to analyse my application BEFORE it goes into production.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have an open-source solution to monitor the performance of RoR applications - https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/rails_performance. It's using Redis to store requests information and in-memory calculations to prepare reports.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

i have not found any thing similar to new_relic but for alternative you can use lots of other gems like

```
gem 'rack-mini-profiler'
gem "bullet"
```

for db performance and query checking, and also you **fire_bug, chrome development tool, Jmeter** for client side performance.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't really an open soruce alternative that can do all the things that New Relic does. But you can use a combination of other gems to help with benchmarking the performance of your application.

Here are a few tools I would try out

Bullet will help with DB queries
https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet

MiniProfiler is also a useful tool for analyzing requests 
http://miniprofiler.com/

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used it myself but I've heard good things about Sensu (http://sensuapp.org/).

It's a general purpose monitoring framework and claims to be an alternative to nagios and the like. I seriously doubt that it comes close to New Relic though regarding things like rendering times and more in-depth information about your app.

Comment: We use Sensu to monitor our servers (disk-space, application availability and a few other stuff) and we also use New Relic. In our case we complement NewRelic with Sensu (for example, we must monitor free inodes too while NewRelic won't monitor those). Se have to set up our checks (or use pre-made ones, as they are compatible with Nagios) and we did that to ensure a headless browser will navigate through some key features in our app correctly. However Sensu is just a monitoring service, it doesn't compete with application performance monitoring tools such as NewRelic.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/sergeyksv/tinelic is supposed to be open source alternative for middle sizes apps. It can accept metrics from new relic agent (you just need to adjust host to make it report to your server). However so far we didn't try it with ruby agents, but in general it should work, you can give a try.